# Probabilities using 3d10 as 1d1000

Tags: dice, statistics, anydice

I'm trying to use anydice to figure out the probabilities of the various values of 1d1000 rolled on 3d10.

I want to know stuff like "what's the chance of rolling 900 or higher?  How about 950 or higher?"

I'm not sure how to script anydice to give me this information if it's actually possible.

Thanks for the help and keep up the good work!